# R-Shiny: Error:could not find function "xpath_element"

Tags: xml, r, shiny, rcurl

I am trying to build some trading data by scrapping data from different website.

It works perfectly under Rstudio, but when I deployed it into my shiny.io, it gave me the following error in the new open browser:

```
Error: could not find function "xpath_element"
```

The packages used in my code are :

```
require(RCurl)
require(rjson)
library(stringr)   # for str_pad
require(ggplot2)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
require(stringr)
```

There are 3 files in my folder, one is server.R, one is ui.R, and one is main.R

```
#main.R:

Sys.setlocale(locale='Chinese')

Analysisf <- function(symbol,param1){

  #ticker1 <- "1"
  ticker1 <- param1
  #ticker2 <- "600030"
  ticker2 <- symbol
  code <- "&code="

  web0 <- paste(ticker1,code,sep="")
  web1 <- paste(web0,ticker2,sep="")
  web2 <- "http://datainterface.eastmoney.com/EM_DataCenter/JS.aspx?type=FD&sty=MTE&mkt="
  web3 <- paste(web2,web1,sep="")
  web4 <- paste(web3,"&p=",sep="")
  cURL <- paste(web4,1:5,sep="")

  fdjson <- getURL(cURL)
  fdjson1 <- substr(fdjson,2,nchar(fdjson)-1)
  fdlist <- sapply(fdjson1,fromJSON)
  fdlist <- strsplit(fdlist,",")
  fdm <- matrix(unlist(fdlist),ncol=13,byrow=T)
  rzrq <- data.frame(fdm)
  rzye <- rzrq[,13]
  rzmr <- rzrq[,11]
  rzch <- rzrq[,10]
  stock <- rzrq[,1]
  date <- as.Date(rzrq[,5])
  rzrq1 <- data.frame(stock,date,rzye,rzmr,rzch)


  ##############################################################################
  ur <- paste("sh",ticker2,sep="")
  web <- "http://app.finance.ifeng.com/hq/stock_daily.php?code="
  url <- paste(web,ur,sep="")

  dat = url %>% html() %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]

  dat <- data.frame(dat)

  dat[,1]=  str_extract(dat[,1],"[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}")
  dat[,7] = str_extract(dat[,7],"[[:digit:]]+")
  date <- as.Date(dat[,1])
  closeprice <- dat[,5]
  volumemoney <- dat[,7]
  stockdat1 <- data.frame(date,closeprice,volumemoney)

  ###############################################################
  u <- "http://stockdata.stock.hexun.com/"
  u0 <- paste(u,ticker2,sep="")
  u1 <- paste(u0,".shtml",sep="")
  url <- htmlParse(u1)
  ltgb <- as.numeric(xmlValue(getNodeSet(url,"//td[@class='tb2_new']")[[10]]))

  ###########
  #merge
  rzrq2 <- data.frame(merge(rzrq1, stockdat1, by='date'))
  rzrq2$ltgb <- ltgb
  rzrq2$date <- as.character(rzrq2$date)

  rzrq2$rmrc <- as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$rzmr))/as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$rzch))

  rzrq2$rzltb <- as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$rzye))/(as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$closeprice))*100000000*rzrq2$ltgb)

  rzrq2$rzcjb <- as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$rzmr))/(as.numeric(as.character(rzrq2$volumemoney))*10000)

  #rownames(stockdat) <- NULL

  return(rzrq2)
}
```

I think the error comes from this file. Because it used some XML methods to get the data from the website.

Can Someone give me some help?

Comment: Please add your actual code, not just the packages & error message.

Comment: the only place i could fine `xpath_element()` on github was here https://github.com/sjp/selectr - Do you use this locally and it's already loaded somehow, but not stated in your project

Comment: `selectr` is a huge dependency for `rvest` as it's what that package uses to turn CSS selectors into XPath selectors. - http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/packages/info/?selectr

Comment: Make sure you've installed all the packages you're using and also verify all their dependencies were installed _correctly_.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I tested this locally and worked, but when I deploy it to https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/login?redirect=%2Fdashboard, it failed to work. I used library(selectr), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: For those who believe in `require()` instead of `library()`, this is just one more piece of evidence that `require()` can be highly confusing. [Read more.](http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I just came across this issue myself... for some reason `install.packages("rvest")` didn't attempt to install `selectr`?? not sure why.